# Return blocks of size X from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a PANDAS dataframe where I want to return a function of every X items of a time series--so for instance, my dataframe might look like

```
date         value
2017-01-01    1
2017-01-02    5
2017-01-03    2
2017-01-04    1
2017-01-05    6
2017-01-06    6
```

So for example, if I want to be able to pull the rolling average of every X values where X is 3, I would want a dataframe showing

```
date         value
2017-01-03    2.666
2017-01-04    2.666
2017-01-05    3
2017-01-06    4.333
```

Is there a dataframe operation that lets me pick a group of X values upon which to run a function?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Comment: @wwii Hi! I would appreciate a hint as to which of the dataframe methods listed in that doc would be applicable to the issue at hand--I'm happy to read through relevant documentation, of course, but there's quite a bit of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with `mean` and then if necessary remove first `NaN`s by `dropna`:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].rolling(3).mean()
df = df.dropna(subset=['value'])
print (df)
        date     value
2 2017-01-03  2.666667
3 2017-01-04  2.666667
4 2017-01-05  3.000000
5 2017-01-06  4.333333
```

There is also possible use `min_periods` parameter for avoid `NaN`s:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
print (df)
        date     value
0 2017-01-01  1.000000
1 2017-01-02  3.000000
2 2017-01-03  2.666667
3 2017-01-04  2.666667
4 2017-01-05  3.000000
5 2017-01-06  4.333333
```

Comment: .rolling() looks like the ticket! Thanks, appreciate the clear and helpful guidance!